# ListBox Scrollviewer Weird behavior

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I have ScrollViewer in the ControlTemplate of my ListBox and I am using .Net 4.0
I am facing two issues on different values of CanContentScroll.

1. when CanContentScroll is True.

   In this case, when I scroll through ListBox with a mouse, ScrollViewer seems to skip 1 or 2 items  randomly out of the view. But SelectedItem's selection works properly.
2. when CanContentScroll is False.

   In this case, scrolling with mouse works fine. but now SelectedItem's selection does not select the actual SelectedItem, but selects the item above or below of it. or continues to display previously  SelectedItem.

please help me out.

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="ListBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ItemContainerStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

ItemContainerSTyle:

```
<Style x:Key="ItemContainerStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource listBoxItemStyle}" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="helper:FluidSelectionAttachedPropertyHelper.IgnoreRightClick" Value="True"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger >
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

ItemTemplate:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="listBoxItemStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Do you have any code/xaml to share with us. Interfaces are a hard thing to debug.

Comment: i added style i am using.

Comment: add your itemcontainer style and ListBoxItem template  and ListBox.ItemTemplate if exist .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all responses.
I found out the solution to alter scroll viewer's vertical scroll speed keeping CanContentScroll is True.

I used attached property to my scroll viewer listbox template and override its PreviewMouseWheel event with following handler method:

```
static void scrollViewer_MouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            var scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
            if (scrollViewer != null)
            {
                var newOffset = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
                if (newOffset < 0 || scrollViewer.ViewportHeight >= scrollViewer.ExtentHeight)
                {
                    newOffset = 0;
                    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(newOffset);
                }
                else if (newOffset + scrollViewer.ViewportHeight >= scrollViewer.ExtentHeight)
                {
                    newOffset = scrollViewer.ExtentHeight - scrollViewer.ViewportHeight;
                    if (e.Delta > 0)
                    {
                        scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(newOffset - 1);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (e.Delta > 0)
                    {
                        scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(newOffset - 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(newOffset + 1);
                    }

                }
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The weird behaviour that you describe is exactly what you asked for using your bizarre `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<Style x:Key="ItemContainerStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource listBoxItemStyle}" 
    TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger >
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Here, you set the items to disappear when they are selected.

For your other, scrolling problem, I would advise you to read the [`ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN as it seems to be working just fine in my opinion:

> The default behavior of the ScrollViewer is to use physical units to scroll its content. However, in cases where the CanContentScroll is set to true, the content could use logical units to scroll.

It should be noted that it can be difficult to spot the difference between these two settings if the items are just `string` based.

Comment: I tried with Visibility=Hidden also. but no use. SelectedItem is still not selected properly.

Comment: Of course you can't select the selected item if it is hidden or collapsed. Why are you trying to hide the selected item? Just get rid of that `ItemContainerStyle` altogether and it will select just fine.

Comment: Actually my requirement is that SelectedItem should not appear in the listbox as it will be added to the cart. so I will have hide it from listbox as per need.

Comment: Well this is *not* how you would achieve that... `Bind` to the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property and when the user selects an item and that property changes in your code, *then* you can remove the item from the collection. This is WPF... we manipulate *data*, not *UI elements*.